Assertion Failure in Eigen Matrix Broadcasting: Dimension Mismatch in Neural Network Forward Pass
I’m implementing a neural network in C++ using Eigen for linear algebra operations. In the DenseLayer::forward function, I’m encountering a dimension mismatch issue when trying to add a bias vector to the layer’s output matrix.
Here’s the structure of my code:

The input matrix has dimensions 64x74 (batch size 64).
weights is initialized with dimensions 128x784.
bias is a column vector of dimensions 128x1.

Expected Behavior:
After multiplying input * weights.transpose(), I get an output matrix of size 64x128. I need to add bias to each row of output so that the final result remains 64x128.
Current Approach:
Here's the forward function:
Eigen::MatrixXd DenseLayer::forward(const Eigen::MatrixXd& input) {
input_cache = input;
Eigen::MatrixXd output = input * weights.transpose();

// Attempt to replicate bias across rows to match output dimensions
Eigen::MatrixXd bias_replicated = bias.replicate(output.rows(), 1);

output += bias_replicated;
return output;
}

Error Message:
When I run the code, I encounter the following assertion failure:
Assertion failed: (dst.rows() == src.rows() && dst.cols() == src.cols()), function resize_if_allowed, file AssignEvaluator.h, line 754.

What I've Tried:

Using .colwise() + bias.col(0), .rowwise() + bias.transpose(), and directly adding bias with different reshaping/transposing.
I've checked dimensions through debug statements and confirmed that output is 64x128 and bias is 128x1.

Question:
How can I correctly broadcast bias across each row of output to perform element-wise addition without Eigen raising a dimension mismatch error? Is there a better way to handle this broadcasting in Eigen, or am I missing something fundamental in matrix addition with Eigen?
Debug Output:
To help, here are the dimensions printed before the error:

Output before bias addition size: 64x128
Bias size for addition: 128x1
Replicated bias size: 64x128

Any insights on achieving the correct broadcasting or a workaround for this would be greatly appreciated!

.rowwise() + bias.transpose() should work. See here on Godbolt. If it doesn't you have to provide a minimal, reproducible example of what you did that failed. You also have a couple of mismatched dimensions in your question, e.g.  at the bottom bias size 129 instead of 128 or further up weight dimensions 128x784. I assume those are typos.

Thank you for the suggestion @Homer512 . You were right that .rowwise() + bias.transpose() should theoretically work for broadcasting, but I encountered issues due to Eigen's static checks when the dimensions of bias were not matching the way .rowwise() expects. Also the bias size 129 was a typo and I have edited the question to fix it. I have also answered my question on how I fixed it. Thank you again for your input!

Here is how I fixed it:
Initial fix which is not efficient and based on Homer512's feedback, I revised my initial approach
Recap on the problem:
The assertion error arose because Eigen's .rowwise() approach requires bias to be treated as a vector for broadcasting along rows. However, Eigen's internal checks often flag mismatches if the vector doesn't conform exactly as expected, especially with transposed vectors in operations like .rowwise() addition.
Solution: Expanding bias into a Full Matrix Before Adding
To work around this limitation, I manually replicated the bias to match the output dimensions before adding it, This ensures that each row of the output matrix receives a copy of the bias vector, making Eigen's type system happy and avoiding the assertion errors.
I Updated forward Function Implementation:
Eigen::MatrixXd DenseLayer::forward(const Eigen::MatrixXd& input) {
     std::cout << "[DenseLayer Forward] Input size: " << input.rows() << "x" << input.cols() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "[DenseLayer Forward] Weights size: " << weights.rows() << "x" << weights.cols() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "[DenseLayer Forward] Bias size: " << bias.rows() << "x" << bias.cols() << std::endl;

     input_cache = input;
     Eigen::MatrixXd output = input * weights.transpose();

     // Create a matrix of the same size as output, where each row is a copy of the bias vector
     Eigen::MatrixXd bias_expanded = bias.transpose().replicate(output.rows(), 1);

     std::cout << "[DenseLayer Forward] Output before bias addition size: " << output.rows() << "x" << output.cols() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "[DenseLayer Forward] Expanded bias size: " << bias_expanded.rows() << "x" << bias_expanded.cols() << std::endl;

     output += bias_expanded;

     std::cout << "[DenseLayer Forward] Output after bias addition size: " << output.rows() << "x" << output.cols() << std::endl;
     return output;
}

Explanation:

Explicit Replication of bias:


bias.transpose().replicate(output.rows(), 1); creates a bias_expanded matrix where each row is a copy of bias. This ensures that bias_expanded has the exact dimensions as output, so if output is 64x128, bias_expanded will also be 64x128.


Avoiding .rowwise() + bias.transpose():


By using this explicit replication, I bypassed .rowwise() entirely. This approach circumvents Eigen's broadcasting limitations and type-checking issues, making the code more robust.

Better Approach: Most recent Fix
Thanks to Homer512's suggestion, I revised my approach for efficiency. Initially, I had bias set up as a matrix, which required full replication to match output dimensions. Now, bias is an Eigen::VectorXd, which broadcasts naturally:
Eigen::MatrixXd DenseLayer::forward(const Eigen::MatrixXd& input) {
   input_cache = input;
   Eigen::MatrixXd output = input * weights.transpose();
   output.rowwise() += bias.transpose(); // Efficient, no full replication needed
   return output;
}

This approach removes the overhead, thanks again!

Your transposed replication is very expensive for what it's doing. An entire replicated matrix? You'd be better off doing output = bias.transpose().replicate(…); then output.noalias() += input * weights.transpose(). Also, why do you have these issues? Is your bias declared as a matrix instead of a vector?

@Homer512 I initially experimented with transposed replication out of curiosity to see how Eigen would handle it for bias addition across each row. It was an interesting approach, but you are absolutely right, the replication added unnecessary overhead. I have made changes based on your suggestions and it avoids the overhead of full replication. Your noalias() tip was also very useful. Thank you

Two more points: 1. Because Eigen stores its values in column-major order, a matrix multiplication of the form A.transpose() * B is often slightly faster. For the same reason, colwise() is faster than rowwise(). Of course for that you need to reorganize the data. 2. It's weird seeing neural network stuff using double precision. Normally you would use single precision MatrixXf.

Thank you, I will try this out @Homer512
